# Whats behind the Times now's android alive application?

Tags: java, android, opencv, javacv

Please don't delete this question because of no code inside this question?

I want to develop an application very similar to [times alive](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adstuck.times.iar), which one enables users to scan images and presents a related video,One of fine AR integration I found.

As per my study its working is this way.It generates key points from camera view and sends them to server and compare it with the key points stored in server server return any related data.

I want exact same features....

After a research  found that most of the ar related articles points to OpenCV  or Java CV, I found a very usefull stuff [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853989/opencv-image-comparison-in-android) but it needs opencv manager have to be installed in the device as a seprate application which is not allowed in my case, and times alive app also not works on that way.

is it possible to develop a similar application using  opencv with out prompt user to install open cv manager, like including it in our application itself(But there are multiple open cv manager for different chip set devices),if yes please can anybody explain the whats the way to accomplish this?

Comment: I have modified the question,Please help me to reopen the question and to get a solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use OpenCV to solve this problem. To me it sounds like it is a process of [feature detection](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_detection/feature_detection.html). You want to extrapolate some key points of the images

THere is some java implementations of feature detection.

Comment: do opencv work with out installing opencv manager in the device?

Comment: The opencv libraries can just be included and built into the application

Comment: thank you for your response,I like to know more a littile, AFAIK there are multiple open cv mangers for support different chepsets, then how can we do this,it would be very helpful if you can suggest me any related tutorials, articles or any thing and especilly your ideas to do this,thank you again for your support