# Android: Image similarity api

Tags: android, space, moonlight

I am developing an application where the User takes a picture of the moon and it will determine the shape and the orientation of the illuminated part of the moon. So I figured the user can take a picture of the moon and it would compare against a set of images I included and match it.  Is there an api to accomplish some of this? Is there any other alternatives?

Comment: google->java image comparison library

Comment: Have a look at it:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853989/opencv-image-comparison-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend opencv image comparison lib. It has some very advanced features that you can  take advantage of. More over, it is very easy to set up and the online documentation is very thorough. there are some great tutorials that you can follow. Though the content can get very technical at some level. 
[OpenCV image comparison in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853989/opencv-image-comparison-in-android)

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html

[Image comparison - fast algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843972/image-comparison-fast-algorithm)