# Java/Android image processing

Tags: java, android, image

I'm thinking of developing an app for android that must be recognized if two images are similar.

- I explain a bit 'better:

  *The user will insert a picture into the application and if the image is similar to a DB contained in the application then takes out the image name.*

A bit ago as the search engine google images:

[Google Image](https://images.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl)

**There is a java object to do this?**

**Do you have any advice for implementation?**

**do you know any example of something similar**?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to load the bitmap and convert it to base64

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

After that is a matter of looking up a normal string in a database. To handle the database I would personally use ormlite.

*EDIT*

For similar images instead of identical, unless the whole point of this exercise it to write the comparison algorithm yourself, you can use opencv. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853989/opencv-image-comparison-in-android) you can find a good stackoverflow answer on the subject.

Comment: ok thanks but this way I get a picture identical, not similar? that's right?

Comment: I misinterpreted the question then. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: do you know any way to find a image similar ?